# Prove: $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \ge \dim V - 2\dim W $

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $ V $ be a linear space over a field $ F $ and let $ W, W_1, W_2 $ be subspaces of $ V$. Assume that $ V = W \oplus W_1 = W \oplus W_2. $ Prove that $$\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \ge \dim V - 2 \dim W.$$

Could you, please, verify the following proof?
$$\dim W_1 + \dim W = \dim V \\
\dim W_2 + \dim W = \dim V$$
\begin{align}
\dim(W_1 + W_2) 
&= \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim (W_1 \cap W_2) \\
&= \dim V - \dim W + \dim V - \dim W - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \\
&= 2 \dim V - 2 \dim W - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)
\end{align}
$$\dim(W_1 + W_2) + \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = 2 \dim V - 2 \dim W$$
Since $W_1 + W_2$ is a subspace of $V$, we have $\dim(W_1 + W_2) \le \dim V$ and, therefore, we get:
$$\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \ge \dim V - 2 \dim W.$$

Comment: Your proof seems perfectly fine.

Comment: just edit the title adding more information